# calling finish() from Activity

Tags: java, android, static, garbage-collection

i want to know that , is `finish();` call effect `static` variables.?
does `static` variables is affected by GC.

```
static int displayChart = 0;
```

code of declaration.

Comment: Try to avoid `static`. There is almost always a better way without. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil

Comment: Correction: avoid static stateful variables aka globals

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`static` variable belongs to `class` not the `object`, and `finish()` or garbage collector affects `object`, therefore it got no influence on `static` variables. Please note that `class` does not equals `object` but `object` is **instance** of `class`.

Comment: but i got problem some time the static variable is display me the null value

Comment: Then please update your question with example of declaration of that variable and more information what `some time` exactly means (other words, what you do to to trigger this issue)

Comment: is it possible that null while my device is goes to in sleep mode ?

Comment: I'd say that would be rather odd

Answer (score 6):

No there is no effect on static variable by calling finish or gc. You can access those variable from other activity for the proof